# Encode and Decode Passwords in WPF Applications

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sha1, password-encryption

I have a WPF applications that contains a user form. I have a password field I need to decript it,  I just have an encrypt method for this:

```
public static string Encode(string value)
    {
        var hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
        var encoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        var combined = encoder.GetBytes(value ?? "");
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash.ComputeHash(combined)).ToLower().Replace("-", "");

    }
```

How to create a Decode method for this?

Comment: what you do is get your string password and go through the same encrypting , then compare to what is stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

The key in this situation is that you don't want to decrypt the password. What you want to do is to encrypt the password entered by the user using the same function and comparing the result to what is stored in the database for the user's account.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is the right thing to do, but you should also hash the value that you are storing in the database and compare the two hashes, you should not, if at all possible, be storing passwords, even if they are encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the one-way hash in the database instead of a reversible encryption.  What the user's actual password happens to be is not your concern, only that the hash of the user supplied password when salted matches the hash in your database.  You might, however, encrypt it for transport to be decrypted at the server and then hashed for storage in the database.

1. Retrieve salt and hashed password from database.
2. Salt candidate password and hash it.
3. Compare values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decrypt SHA1 hash because it's a one way hash. Hashing is not a reversible operation.

Below a helper class that both encrypt and decrypte a string

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EncryptStringSample
{
    public static class StringCipher
    {
        // This constant string is used as a "salt" value for the PasswordDeriveBytes function calls.
        // This size of the IV (in bytes) must = (keysize / 8).  Default keysize is 256, so the IV must be
        // 32 bytes long.  Using a 16 character string here gives us 32 bytes when converted to a byte array.
        private static readonly byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tu89geji340t89u2");

        // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm.
        private const int keysize = 256;

        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
        {
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
            {
                byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
                using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                                byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                                return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
        {
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using(PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
            {
                byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
                using(RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using(ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                    {
                        using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                        {
                            using(CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                                int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above class can used quite simply with code similar to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace EncryptStringSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a password to use:");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a string to encrypt:");
            string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Your encrypted string is:");
            string encryptedstring = StringCipher.Encrypt(plaintext, password);
            Console.WriteLine(encryptedstring);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Your decrypted string is:");
            string decryptedstring = StringCipher.Decrypt(encryptedstring, password);
            Console.WriteLine(decryptedstring);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another way to decrypt and encrypt using RSA

Replace your_rsa_key with your RSA key.

```
 var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    provider.ImportParameters(your_rsa_key);

    var encryptedBytes = provider.Encrypt(
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!"), true);

    string decryptedTest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
        provider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true));
```

Here's a good link on how [RSA](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/rsa-algorithm-with-C-Sharp2/) works with a clear exmaple

Comment: in your first exemple above how can a get StringCipher.Decrypt(encryptedstring, password); from another class?

Answer (score 0):

SHA1 is a hash function which means it is basically one-way function, you cannot get the original content back.

you should use cryptographic functions if you need to get the original value back.
there basically two classes of encryption algorithms - symmetric and asymmetric cryptographic functions.

- symetric is for example AES
- asymetric  would be Public/private key encrytion such as RSA

take a look at this sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET